# Power BI Error: Value 'preferred' is not of the correct type

Tags: mysql, powerbi

I am trying to connect MySQL with Power BI. When I choose "Get Data" from MySQL database I get this error:
"Value 'preferred' is not of the correct type"

I have installed the Connector and installed and uninstall several times Power BI. What is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that somewhere in powerbi there is a mapping for the columns and this `preferred` column is been mapped to the wrong counterpart. Essentially **it is like** if `preferred` is a varchar value and it is trying to map it to a number value (this is an example)

Comment: If the query has a step: Changed Type, then try deleting that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the latest MySQL Connector/Net version 8.0.11 installed and got the same error.  I uninstalled and installed version 6.10.7 and it worked.

Comment: In my case after the downgrade I got the error: Details: "MySQL: Fatal error encountered during command execution.". Any suggestion?

Comment: Great! Downgrade works for me. I'm connecting to MariaDB ColumnStore.